# Float bar near bottom from any size

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a page with a bar at the bottom which floats over a background. This will be going on a phone so the sizes will change. I need the bottom bar to move up if the screensize is too small (i.e. it will get hidden how I've done it at the moment). To clarify, the bar with the arrows on works properly, it's the bar with the text in it that's opaque that needs to move.

At the moment it looks like:

[image]

which works fine, however when the browser is resized the following happens:
[image]

The code is like:

```
<div class="home_slide2" id="slide2" name="slide2" ng-swipe-right="go('/slideone')" ng-swipe-left="go('/slidethree')">
    <div class="home_bar">text in the bar
    <div id="submit" class="intro_btn" name="submit">Join</div>
    </div>
        </div>
    <div class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse">
    <div class=" footerbar no-gutter">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="images/slider_prev.png" ng-click="go('/slideone')"  class="navbar-arrow" /></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <center>
            <img src="images/invisible_dot.png"  style="display:inline-block; width:100%; max-width:15px;">
            <img src="images/visible_dot.png" style="display:inline-block; width:100%; max-width:15px;">
            <img src="images/invisible_dot.png"  style="display:inline-block; width:100%; max-width:15px;">
            </center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="images/slider_next.png" ng-click="go('/slidethree')" class="pull-right navbar-arrow" /></div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.home_bar{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 200px;
    top: 54%;
}


.home_slide2{
   background: url(../images/slide2.jpg) no-repeat scroll 5% center / cover #fff;
    height: 600px;
    top: 59px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Comment: There is missing html in your code above.... no closing tags

Comment: I think u need to add a padding: something%; to the bottom of it.

Comment: I am correct in thinking your just want the transparent box to grow in height if content is larger then the available space but remain fixed to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Basically the bar should move up the page if the height is too small

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly these changes should:

- Fix the transparnet div to the bottom
- Set a min height
- Grow if content becomes larger than your min height.

**CSS**

```
.home_slide2{
    position:relative; /*add relative to home_bar's container.*/
}
.home_bar{
    position:fixed; /* fix to bottom */
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto; /* grow UPWARD if content larger than min height */
    min-height:200px; /* set min height */
    bottom: 0; /* fix to bottom */
    width:100%; /* Fill width */
}
```

### DEMO